# How to prevent memory editing to prevent hooking

Tags: windows, memory, hook

I recently learned inline hooking x32 and x64 which is based on overwriting the first bytes of the function with a jmp to the hooking function or by pushing the 64 address to rax then jmp rax to perform a far jmp on x64 architecture
I also learned iat hooking and delay imports hooking which requires editing an offest holding function address in the import table to point to my hook function
Also hooking by exceptions requires editing at least the first byte to an unknown byte so an exception will be thrown and you will catch it with your already installed handler and redirect to your trampoline

All these types of hooking requires editing memory and the memory usually is PAGE_EXECUTEREAD for functions or read only for the import table

So the attacker will use VirtualProtect or NtVirtualProtect to be able to edit the bytes

One more hooking method is via guard exceptions which almost doesn't require any editing to the bytes but to the memory protection so an exception will be raised on accessing the function and you will handle them and do whatever you want

So these methods all require changing the protection of the memory so i think of hooking VirtualProtect and NtVirtualProtect to prevent any edit for particular addresses but the hooker can unhook the functions and bypass this

I heard about new mitigations such dynamic code generation preventing but I need to allocate some executable code so I can't use this and it won't protect against iat hooking and guard exceptions hooking

Is there really a method to full defend against hooking or at least make it very hard ?

Comment: What is the threat scenario here? A chaotic admin (VirtualProtect and NTVirtualProtect require elevated privileges), a random malware, or a specific malware targetted against your application?

Comment: No it doesn't require admin privileges , you can use them easily from a non admin running program

Comment: VirtualProtect can only access pages of current process and VirtualProtectEx require the  PROCESS_VM_OPERATION access right on an external process. As I assume you do not want to protect a process against itself, I ask again *what is the threat*?

Comment: @SergeBallesta He can use ObRegisterCallbacks to prevent handle creation and duplication to specific targets, but obviously he intentionally wants to screw things up because he is focus-obsessed on the whole API hooking scenario. So let him hook the APIs and mess things up and hopefully he will learn from his mistakes.

Comment: I can't make a kernel driver because I can't buy a digital certificate to sign the driver now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can't protect from hooking entirely. Still hacker can modify you executable file on disk in such a way that it won't install hooks. Or he just can install hooks inside your executable himself.

To prevent this actually there are a lot of techniques. For example, you can do a lot of checks for modification of your program. You can do hidden checks for modification of particular sections of code in program and you can obfuscate your code. There are many other techniques, that are usually combined to make an efficient software protection system. But none of the ways can make your code fully protected from hacker's modifications. If there was such a protection, no software/game would be pirated. Now pirating software which is distributed to clients is only a matter of difficulty. The more complicated protection system is, the more time it takes to hack it. But it's never impossible.

Comment: You forgot a major point: the more complicated protection, the worse user/admin experience. I remember spending hours to make 2 protected software cooperate on the same machine while my organization had payed the license fees: both supports just said that the other application was the culprit. We later decided to no longer buy any protected software.

Comment: editing the original file will be detected from users as the date of last write will change . Also I'm not publishing a game but anti user mode rootkit so malwares that uses this technique will be detected by my app . You w may say that antivirus would do the job but in fact these companies are too lazy to implement such thing . I tested hooking user mode functions myself and the antivirus was full blind

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's not always so. Well, in most cases, there is such problem. But there is no proportion between the amount of protection and user experience spoiling. It's the matter of software quality. Protection system of poor quality will do user a lot of pain and won't prevent hacker from hacking it. Remember those game CDs with a long and painful CD-check which can be easily avoid. And good protection system won't make user even notice itself. One of the aim of protection system developer is making protection system unnoticeable for user.

Comment: @dev65 Well you know that user-mode hooking is only for your current process? You are modifying executable code inside memory(function `VirtualProtect`) of your process to ensure this very process won't call function `VirtualProtect`?

Comment: These malwares hook nearly all running processes by hooking CreateProcess in the parent processes which will hook the child process and so on . And they hook some nt functions like NtQuerySystemInformation and other functions that lead to detect the malware pid or even the path of the executable as they hook NtQueryDirectoryFile so the malware will be hidden from any user mode application so firstly I need to remove the hooks then prevent being hooked again

Comment: @dev65: If you really think that controlling the date of last write is enough to detect file modification, please keep away from security. Powershell on windows, or touch on Unix/Linux cat reset files timestamp, just read this [question](https://superuser.com/q/292630) from PowerUser. And hopefull antivirus do not flag programs using VirtualProtect because it is a referenced function from WinAPI and **has** valid use case...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, that's totally right, any timestamp can be written when file is saved. And `VirtualProtect` is called on simple memory allocation.

Comment: I don't want them to prevent memory allocation but pretect against some malwares such zeus and its competitors . Really the defense against such attacks isn't very hard I now can protect myself against zeus even it's understandable but I want to publish a public tool so I'm afraid that malware developers will adapt to this tool and find some ways to get around it

Answer (score 0):

To prevent memory editing which in turn may prevent hooking, proper configurations for the process must be in place. Attackers will modify code through calls to [WriteProcessMemory/NtWriteVirtualMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) when the specified memory is passed into the call. Attackers will use these routines regardless of if they are executing within the context of the process they are modifying. There are various other ways to write memory within the process as well that attackers may use which I will go over how to protect from.

Do note that you cannot prevent WriteProcessMemory/NtWriteVirtualMemory calls from modifying code from user-mode without proper attributes being configured for the pages containing the addresses being modified. When NtWriteVirtualMemory initiates a system service request, the kernel handles the rest.

From a kernel-mode standpoint, the API provided for Windows drivers does provide a routine that registers callbacks for operations on certain types of handles such as process and thread handles. This routine is called [ObRegisterCallbacks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-obregistercallbacks). Some software uses this routine to prevent certain operations on their handle(s) from being complete.

ObRegisterCallbacks can register callbacks for the following types of handle operations

- Process handles
- Thread handles
- Desktop handles

Preventing specific operations on a designated process handle can prevent system service requests such as NtWriteVirtualMemory (WriteProcessMemory) and NtProtectVirtualMemory ([VirtualProtect/Ex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366899(v=vs.85).aspx)) from being complete. Doing so prevents the attacker from writing memory to your process through a service request and it prevents them from changing the protections of virtual pages in your process.

From a user-mode standpoint, you are much more limited in terms of being able to read the kernel data structures for objects such as processes and threads and you are much more limited in what types of routines you can call. WriteProcessMemory cannot be prevented if the attacker just decides to call VirtualProtectEx and change the page from read-only/execute to read/write/execute.

A strong configuration for the code and data sections of your process will still go a long way though. In fact, it's important to make sure any and all security descriptors, DACLs, etc., in your process are properly configured. First and foremost, make sure that your code pages are read-only/execute. Each process contains a [VAD (virtual address descriptor) tree (implemented as an AVL tree)](https://resources.infosecinstitute.com/finding-enumerating-processes-within-memory-part-2/) to the kernel. A VAD contains the attributes and flags for a range of virtual addresses in your process. Such attributes and flags include the various types of protections such as read/write/execute, copy on write, whether memory is committed/reserved, etc...

There is a flag used in VAD flags called SecNoChange. If you remap the code section in your process using [NtCreateSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwcreatesection) then pass SecNoChange in the AllocationAttributes and then call [NtMapViewOfSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection) to map the memory back into the process, then it will make calls such as NtProtectVirtualMemory fail. This will prevent attackers from modifying the page attributes for your code so that they can't cause arbitrary exceptions and handle them to redirect code, nor can they change the protections if they are read-only/execute to write to that memory. Writing to read-only memory will of course fail. This is where it would be important for the code pages to be marked as read-only/execute instead of read/write/execute, so that the attacker cannot change the protection nor write to the address range.

Even with your sections configured with SecNoChange, it also does not hurt to have additional mitigation techniques such as memory integrity checks. At the basic level, memory integrity checks generally work by hashing the contents of the memory of a group of pages and verifying the integrity of the next cycle with the first hash generated, if the hashes differ, then memory has been modified and the program may terminate its current activity.

Windows provides many types of mitigation techniques and policies. I'd also look into [process mitigation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setprocessmitigationpolicy) provided by Windows.

Comment: But WriteProcessMemory isn't a necessary if you are already in the target process (from dll) and preventing the OpenProcess and CreateRemoteThread isn't the best solution as this will prevent debuggers from debugging the process (I'm not trying to protect my process but another one) the attacker can use memcpy or simply a thing like this : void copy(void *v,const void *v2,size_t sz){for (size_t i=0;i<sz;++i){((PUCHAR)v)[i] = ((PUCHAR)v2)[i]}} the solution is to have the function in unknown address and the original function will be a fake one , pretty yes ?

Comment: That can obscure your code, but there is the possibility that the attacker is doing a signature scan and finds multiple references of the same function and decides to modify all of them. Remapping the sections with SecNoChange will prevent the attacker from successfully calling VirtualProtect which will also make memcpy and other memory writing functions fail in the first place if the memory is read-only/execute. Using SecNoChange with correct page protections will prevent memory editing.

Comment: When the section is already mapped into the process, suspend execution of the process during this operation and then make a temporary copy of the section's memory and unmap the section using NtUnmapViewOfSection. Then create a new section with SEC_NOCHANGE passed as the allocation attribute using NtCreateSection. After creating the section, you can map it at the same base address as the old section with NtMapViewOfSection and copy the temporary buffer into the new section and then the temporary buffer can be deleted and process execution can be restored. This will prevent editing pages.

Comment: Really useful info . But in my case the process needs to allocate executable code so I'll break the process . If I could prevent any executable code generation I would use process mitigations as the process will be protected from the kernel so the attacker needs a kernel rootkit to allocate hooks but the solution you provided can be bypassed by remapping the section again but the good thing is that it isn't famous way so most attackers won't know what happened !!!

Answer (score -2):

I had a good solution
If I want to not be affected by hooking simply don't use the hooked functions directly but from a trampoline so the attacker must know the address of your trampoline